# How to post Text to facebook using facebook sdk 4.5.1 for android?

Tags: facebook, text

How to post Text to facebook using facebook sdk 4.5.1 for android?
Please help me!
Thank so much!

Comment: Please explain your problem in details also tell what all you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a sample app inside the SDK. Please check.